Xcode Build Fails with TensorFlowLite on Kotlin Multiplatform: ld: framework 'TensorFlowLiteC' not found
I am developing a Kotlin Multiplatform project that includes TensorFlow Lite for both iOS and Android targets. I can install CocoaPods and use TensorFlow Lite within iOS, but when I attempt to access it from Kotlin Multiplatform, my Xcode build fails. Below is the relevant configuration from my build.gradle.kts for the shared module:
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
}

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
    targetHierarchy.default()

    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Machine Learning on KMP"
        homepage = "https://company.com"
        version = "1.0"

        pod("TensorFlowLiteObjC") {
            moduleName = "TFLTensorFlowLite"
            podfile = file("../iosSicuraApp/Podfile")
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {}
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:${Versions.kotlinCoroutinesNative}")
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.company.customTFLib"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
    }
}

When I try to build, I get the following error in Xcode:
> Task :shared:linkDebugFrameworkIosSimulatorArm64 FAILED

ld: framework 'TensorFlowLiteC' not found


The error suggests that the TensorFlowLiteC framework is not being found during the linking phase.
What I have tried:

Ensuring that CocoaPods are correctly installed and accessible.
Verifying paths and dependencies in the Podfile and build.gradle.kts.
Cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Questions:

How can I resolve the linking error regarding the TensorFlowLiteC framework not being found?
Are there any specific configurations or settings that I should check or modify in my - - Kotlin Multiplatform setup to ensure that the iOS build can correctly link to the TensorFlowLiteC framework?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

